# System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Dim filePath As String = "~/Images/FleaMarket/uploadedImages/" & User.Identity.Name.ToString & "/" & itemID & Path.GetExtension(fuImage.FileName)
        MsgBox(filePath)
        If fuImage.HasFile Then
            If Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Images/FleaMarket/uploadedImages/" & User.Identity.Name.ToString & "/")) = False Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Images/FleaMarket/uploadedImages/" & User.Identity.Name.ToString & "/"))
            End If
            'lblMessage.Text = ""
            If checkFileType(fuImage.FileName) Then

                fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Images/FleaMarket/uploadedImages/" & User.Identity.Name.ToString))
```

i get an error **"System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\TriceDealsII Updated\13-10-11\Tricedeals II(4)\Images\FleaMarket\uploadedImages\mitali2054' is denied"**

why??

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Applications, which run in IIS use the User assigned to the specified Application Pool. For each Application Pool there will be a Windows User which is part of the Windows Group "IIS_IUSRS". As this User / Group do not have Write/Change Access to the directory of your Webapplication (or any other directory) you must manually grant these permissions.

To achive this: Navigate in the explorer to the specified path, where you wish to write your files / data open the Security Page of the directory to add the User of your AppPool or the Group "IIS_IUSRS" to the List and select the write (or change) permission.

Note: Write permission is always a security risk. Therefore you should restrict it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by a permissions issue on the file you're trying to access. You could try [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see if it will tell you what account is trying to access the file then grant the necessary permissions to that account.