# System.UnauthorizedAccessException in Server.MapPath()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement to upload word files to a folder in my solution file so that I can display it w.r.t to each user who has uploaded it. I successfully uploaded the files to a folder. Right Now, I want to sent the user's details and the uploaded word to the system admin.

But I am facing a System.UnauthorizedAccessException. in the below line of code.

```
Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment((Server.MapPath(filePath))));
```

The detailed exception message is as below:

> *ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.  To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file
>   in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab.
>   Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the
>   ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.*

Please help me sort the issue..

Comment: You to add read permission for anonymous user in that folder.

Comment: Did you try what the message suggests? It's telling you how to fix the problem...

Comment: I enabled anonymous authentication. I also granted full control to the user

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.UnauthorizedAccessException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869297/system-unauthorizedaccessexception)

Answer (score 2):

Grant the full persmission to ASP.Net account or Network service account. or check whether these account has got full access permission on Temp folder...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Lingaraj's proposed solution, and please check if IIS_IUSERS user has the necessary permissions on the folder that you upload your files.

Comment: Yes. I granted permisiion for IIS_IUSERS. Still Some issues!!

Answer (score -2):

Grant permission as Everyone to folder where you deployed website.